# What's the difference between JSPs and AJAX?

Tags: ajax, jsp, spring-mvc

I ask, because they both provide connectivity to the server, they can both potentially draw information from the database, and so forth.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

JSP, JavaServer Page has directives and html that are converted into a Java Servlet. The JSP tags produce java code that generates a response(generally an HTML page, but it can respond with other resources). The HTML is printed out via HTTP response from a given HTTP request. A JSP is invoked by a Server Container upon a given URL requests.

AJAX, Asynchronous Javascript and XML. This is executed client side in browswer and makes requests to the server for specific information. The information returned from the server needs to be handled on the client machine with javascript. AJAX can request a JSP page, JSON objects, XML and other mime-types. AJAX pretty much invokes the HTTP requests to the server.

Answer (score 0):

A Java Server Page, served by a Java container like Tomcat, becomes a Java class that is executed on the server and is vended to the browser as a HTML page. It can include JSP tags and directives.  Some tags simply expand into Java content to be executed. Others expand into ordinary text to be included in the HTML file. This can include Javascript, of course.

For example, Apache Struts works with the Jakarta Commons Validator project, which when configured correctly, both provides server-side validation and generates Javascript to do client-side validation.

There are JSTL tags that talk to databases; these are in the sql namespace.  But the work is done on the server.

However, nothing in a JSP naturally causes AJAX to be invoked. You can put AJAX calls in your JSP, or you can use tags that generate AJAX calls. The two ideas are mostly independent.